# C# "deteriorating" list?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a list of work that I'm trying to work on until all work is depleted, but not sure how to handle this.  The idea I'm trying to emulate is:

```
foreach(Work w in _workList) {
   res = DoSomethingOnWork(w);
   if(res) {
       _workList.Remove(w);
   }
}
```

Reason being, when in "DoSomethingForWork(w)" the work may not be what I want to do at that moment, so I'll skip that one and move on to the next.  When I'm at the end of the list, I want to go back through the list.  Before I go write a collection to handle this, I was curious if there was already something in .NET for handling this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know if it's an elegant solution, but sometime, I create another list which will contain the list of element to remove from the orginal list. Then I just do another for each after to remove from the original list all element from my new list.

Comment: @David: If your collection permits random access, you can use a `while` or `for` loop on the original list, making sure to loop from back to front.  Removing an item from the back of a collection won't break this.  You can do something similar (in either order) with a `LinkedList`.

Comment: I don't know, each time I used a List (Of...), it would not permit me to remove object during a foreach, so I assumed that it couldn't be done.

Comment: @DavidBrunelle: Yes, that's why I said you would need to use a `while` or `for` loop (**instead** of a `foreach` loop).  Doing this is safe if done correctly, though it will be more or less efficient than creating another list, depending.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sort of thing is what [the Queue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) is for. It holds a collection, and you just dequeue each item to work it. It is a last-in, last-out collection.

If you decide to skip one, you can requeue it for later.

You can also take a look at [the Stack class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx), which is similar but is a last-in, first-out collection.

Comment: Heh, completely thought over the Queue.  Thanks much!

Comment: I'm not sure how queue makes this problem any different. It's _still_ `get item; check item; remove item;`  except now it's `remove item; check item; add item back;`

Comment: The problem is the same. The question was about which collection class to use for best results. Some collection classes won't let you remove items while you're in the middle of a loop iterating/enumerating that collection.

Comment: Are you insinuating that `Queue<T>` will?

Comment: No, you don't need an iterator. while (oQueue.Count > 0) { object o = oQueue.Dequeue();} You can enqueue while in that loop and Count reflects the change properly at the top of the loop. This can be a pain to implement with other collection types (how much of one depends on the type). See Eric's answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is extremely dangerous to *modify* a collection while you are *iterating* over it; doing so is a recipe for crashes.

What I would do you in your case is use a Queue, or possibly get a little fancier and implement a priority queue. A queue has the property that the most recently adding thing is the last one to be serviced, just like a queue at a bank; you join the end of the line, and everyone before you is serviced first. So your loop would look something like this:

```
while(queue.Count > 0)
{
    var currentCustomer = queue.Dequeue();
    bool success = ServiceCustomer(currentCustomer);
    if (!success)
    {
        // the customer couldn't be serviced. Send them to the
        // back of the line so that we service other customers before 
        // trying again.
        queue.Enqueue(currentCustomer);
    }
}
```

A PriorityQueue works just like a queue except that each task gets a priority associated with it. Higher-priority tasks get to be VIPs and jump the queue to be in front of lower-priority tasks. It is not too hard to implement your own priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're working with removing items from a list, you can't do a foreach because that causes an enumerator to get created which throws an exception when the list is edited... Use a for loop in reverse:

```
for(int i = _workList.Count(); _workList.Count()> 0; i--){
   w = _workList[i];
   res = DoSomethingOnWork(w);
   if(res) {
       _workList.Remove(w);
   }
   // Handle reseting i once we've looped through entire list
   if(i == 0){
       i = _workList.Count() - 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linq, and your collection implements IQueryable, you can filter the collection based on a given lambda:

```
_workList.Where((work) => 
{
  return !DoSomethingOnWork(work);
});
```

This will return all elements in _workList for which DoSomethingOnWork(work) returns false;

Answer (score 0):

Another option is for you `Work` class to contain a property like `IsCompleted` and simply:

```
if (!w.IsCompleted) w.IsCompleted = DoSometingForWork(w);
```

Very straight forward, readable, easy to maintain, and new programmers should get what it's doing.

If your loop is reoccurring you can:

```
foreach (Work w in _WorkList.Select(x => !x.IsCompleted))
```